# Crashes with out comprehensible Stacktrace

Tags: android, android-webview

does anyone has a clue where an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException comes from with those stacktraces?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=1; index=7
LE2.b (LE2.java:1)
JE2.onItemClick (JE2.java:3)
android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick (AdapterView.java:350)
```

or

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException length=1; index=7
OI.a (OI.java:1)
MI.onItemClick (MI.java:3)
android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick (AdapterView.java:374)
```

The things i know: It has something to do with a WebView. The second error is 100% on Android 10 (until now).

Thanks for any help!

edit: It turns it that there is a bug with a year spinner at the registration inside the webview. The visualised list of years isnt updated correctly. But i dont know how we can fix it because its a simple html feature.

Comment: looks like you should deobfuscate your logs

Comment: it seems to be already deobfuscated. i took the mapping.txt and the stacktrace and

sh retrace.sh mapping.txt test.txt

gave me the same stacktrace.

Comment: its a bug within a spinner inside the webview.

Comment: the weird thing is '.a' (unless you called it a - FOR SHAME) is usally the sign of obfuscation, so I don't think you have the correct mapping file is that is the case, the way that it works, is if you dont have the right mapping file, it just won't do anything. Are you sure?